# I have uninstalled and then again reinstalled openfire in Ubuntu 16.04, but after that openfire.sh file is missing in init.d directory

Tags: 16.04, init.d

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/openfire: command not found
```

I checked `etc/init.d` directory. I found no file there and openfire setup is installed. What should I do? I am just stuck here. Please help me.

Comment: How exactly did you try to install `openfire`? The Debian package that can be downloaded contains an `/etc/init.d/`script.

Comment: Debian package @Thomas

Comment: So you did download the `openfire_4.1.0_all.deb` file and then installed it with `dpkg -i openfire_4.1.0_all.deb`? Any errors or warnings?

Comment: I already install/uninstall it so many times in every possible way but still file is not generating in init.it directory?? i do not know now wt to do. @Thomas

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep -i openfire` output? If it does not output anything, go to a terminal and execute `sudo dpkg -i /<full-path-to-file>/openfire_4.1.0_all.deb`.

Comment: Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu13) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot

Comment: rajnesh@rajnesh-Inspiron-3558:/opt$ dpkg -l | grep -i openfire
ii  openfire                                  4.1.0                                               all          A high performance XMPP (Jabber) server.

Comment: i reboot it after that but again same error of file missing

Comment: i used this link to uninstall openfire, http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.in/2009/11/uninstall-openfire-from-ubuntu-system.html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50826/discussion-between-user2968961-and-thomas).